# X and Y matrices

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Should matrix X contain column that want to predict (Y)?

Let we have dataframe like this:

```
val1      val2     val3
126.25   9.343    59.1
131.75   8.359    70.2
102.5    24.671   16.3
110.5    5.015    29.0
101.25   12.015   13.7
140.5    16.015   54.9
```

Column to predict is val3. So  val3 will be `Y`, and I wonder if `X` should contain just `val1` and `val2` or all 3 columns. For example to predict we would use simple neurone network.

Comment: I mean, come on... does it matter?

Comment: cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sure it does!

Comment: No, it doesn't. You write your code accordingly. Convention (and common sense) dictate they be separate, but you are free to do what you want.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it doesn't matter how to call variables, but it _does_ matter what to feed to the model. ;-) The model should NOT be able to see your target (`val3`) in the training vector (usually called `X_train`) - otherwise you'll have a 100% score (with high probability) on the training data and very bad score for the test data. It's called `data leakage`

Comment: Ok, so val3 is your labels (typically called Y), and X might be a single channel or it might have two channels - you could try both. Do you have more data (I don't need to see it, but this dataset seems quite small for a neural network - you'll need a training set and a test set)? Do you have to use a neural network or is there a simpler way? What have you done so far?

Comment: @MaxU Didn't get your notification for some reason... but thanks, that's helpful to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building a model that will be implemented in the real world and not just for research purposes etc...

Assuming this is a time series problem. Your X data should only contain information that will be available to the model at the time of prediction. Example.. if predicting next month's sales your algorithm won't have the actual sales numbers available for that month so it shouldn't be included. It will, however, have access to **previous** month's sales numbers. So the lag of the target variable can be used.

```
df["lag_1"] = df["val3"].shift(1)
df["lag_2"] = df["val3"].shift(2)
df["lag_3"] = df["val3"].shift(3)
```

Then just drop the NA's that this will produce and you have 3 new features you can feed into the network.

If this isn't a time series then I would just say no, you shouldn't include the target. The network will use that information and give you a perfect prediction that is not realistic performance.

**Edit**
To your question...

The format I describe above would still be formatted for a standard neural network. To format for a RNN it would need to be a window of the values and that would look like this for one example with 3 features and a window length of 3.

```
[[var1_lag3, var1_lag2, var1_lag1],
 [var2_lag3, var2_lag2, var2_lag1],
 [var3_lag3, var3_lag2, var3_lag1]
]
```

Comment: so in RNN all the 3 columns would be in X?

Comment: thank you for explication. And should Y have the same form as X ?`[[var3_lag1],
 [var3_lag2],
 [var3_lag3]
]`

Comment: Y, in this case for one example, would just be [var3,] since it would be predicting the "current" value.